# Push custom variable from Gmail to specific GA event after event was fired

Tags: google-analytics, event-handling, google-tag-manager, measurement-protocol

I have GA event "Form submitted" which fires after user submits the form on my website.
After that I go to my Gmail and check if request was relevant looking through email description (user request).
What I want to do is to add to these emails buttons "relevant" and "not relevant" and push the data to a custom dimension (or custom variable) "Request Value" to each "Form submitted" event by clicking on those buttons.

**Long story short:**
User sends me email through "request form" -> GA event "Form submitted" is fired -> I go to Gmail and click "relevant" button in email -> Data goes to GA event "Form submitted" to a specific user.

The question is.. How URLs should look like in these buttons and how to setup my desired configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can direct the user to your site in a specific page for both cases and consequently send to Analytics the custom dimension with one or the other value. Obviously the dimension must be activated in Google Analytics. In GTM you can set it the GA tag advanced settings, defining cd index and value.

Comment: Thanks Michele! But if user has already sent me a request and I've got an email so how can I land him to a specific page? I need to click "relevant" or "not relevant" in email in order to send data to GA.

Comment: When user click on relevant direct him to one thankyou page and not relevant to another.

Comment: The thing is user doesn't click, I click. User sends me the request, I open Gmail and find the request, look through it and have two buttons in email. Relevant and not relevant. After that I click on one of the buttons and want to send data to GA.

Comment: If you don't want to reconcile the data with the user who made the request, it does not change, you will open one of the two pages. If instead you want to reconcile the data then the matter becomes more complicated, you have to get the clientid of the user and then make a call with the measurement protocol using that as the value of the cid parameter.

Comment: Yes, that is what Im looking for. How to transfer сid to email letter and after clicking the button push it back with an event in order to reconcile the data with the user.
Many thanks for your help, Michele! I would be very thankful if you describe this process with more details.